# What will happen if set java_home and classpath to different java version?

Tags: java, classpath

For example , I have 2 java versions: /usr/jdk8 and /usr/jdk7.

If I set java_home to jdk8 but set classpath to lib in jdk7, which version will be actually in use if I just run java -xx command?

I think it will be jdk7 as the rt.jar in jdk7 will be loaded.

**What really confused me is what information the java command itself has, and what it does in the whole process when java program runs**, while I can understand that there are lots of java core codes in rt.jar.

It's not easy to search the question, as I will always get "how to config java_home" kind of things.

I hope I described my confusion clearly . It's better if someone can give me some living example to help understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not try it yourself and see what happens?

Comment: As far as Java is concerned there isn't any need to set either of them. It's hard to see what the point of deliberately getting this wrong would be, or why the answer is of any real use.

Comment: @Sweeper . I will try that, of course, but I think it will not be very helpful to understand the java command. So I ask the question in advance, hoping some good advice, and it will help me to find better test cases to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath is not used for finding the Java Runtime Library, so adding Java Runtime jars to the classpath will have no impact.

See Java documentation: [How Classes are Found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)

It describes that classes that comprise the Java platform, including the classes in `rt.jar` and several other important jar files, are loaded from the "bootstrap classpath", which is different from the "user classpath".

For more information, read more at [JDK Tools and Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#general), i.e. to learn more, read the documentation. It is there for a reason.

Comment: year, so I got that wrong all the time about the classpath. thx

Answer (score 0):

> What really confused me is what information the java command itself has, and what it does in the whole process when java program runs

The only information it has and needs is its own .exe location.

- It sets its own CLASSPATH accordingly
- It makes no use of JAVA_HOME at all. Only IDEs, Tomcat, etc., do that.

Comment: First bullet is technically correct, but woefully incomplete. The `java` command will set the "user classpath" to the current directory, by default, but will use a specified classpath if given, using `-cp` command-line option or `CLASSPATH` environment variable.